# How can the dual-boot screen be obtained?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a system, dual-boot along with windows 10. However, after installation, the system directly boots into Ubuntu and the selection for Windows is not shown. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this workaround**

Perform these commands as sudo :-

```
/etc/grub.d/

gedit 40_custom
```

adds following lines in 40_custom file:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  chainloader +1
}
```

If that fails try this instead:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
      set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
      chainloader +1
    }
```

after edit save file and run following command :

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

It add windows entry in the main configuration file.

then type:

```
reboot
```

Comment: I love your faith in humanity ;) Usually these questions end with the comment, "omg, I blew away my entire Windows partition... how do I get it back? I have no backup"  :p