# can't boot into win 10 after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, grub

I had windows 10 with three partitions then I installed Ubuntu on the free one. on installation I have  chosen advanced options and manually chose a specific partition for Ubuntu installation. when restart my computer after am done with installation, It just directly boots into Ubuntu with out showing the boatloader. I can access all the partition from my Ubuntu installation how can I correct this so that I can get a grub boot loader to choose and boot into any of my OS. please help.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1216920/how-can-the-dual-boot-screen-be-obtained/1216959

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the dual-boot screen be obtained?](https://superuser.com/questions/1216920/how-can-the-dual-boot-screen-be-obtained)